# Drag and drop entre vistas y regiones con PRISM 4

Tags: .net, wpf, mvvm

Estoy tratando de arrastrar una vista a otra región con PRISM, y hasta ahora no lo he conseguido.
¿Es posible? ¿Soporta PRISM 4 esta operación? 
Si no lo soporta ¿Cuál sería la solución alternativa?
En el libro de referencia de PRISM: "Developers Guide To Microsoft PRISM 4" no viene nada al respecto, y tampoco he encontrado información muy clara hasta ahora en google.

Gracias por anticipado.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes combinar Prism con Dragablz y conseguir ese efecto.

Tienes más información en https://github.com/ButchersBoy/Dragablz

Espero que te sea de utilidad.

Comment: Seria mejor que en ves de dejar solo un link publicaras aquí la solución.